# Counting the number of consecutive binary indicators in a time series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe that uses binary indicators to reflect whether a customer is live during a particular month. If the customer is live, there is a 1, if not there is a 0. The dataframe looks like the below:

```
Customer    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
11/30/2015  1   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
12/31/2015  0   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   1
1/31/2016   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1
2/29/2016   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
3/31/2016   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   1
4/30/2016   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1
5/31/2016   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1
```

When a customer is live, they get a 1 for the particular month. Similarly, if they are live in the following month (or any month) they get a 1 for that month also.

I want to add a column at the end of the dataframe which counts the number of customers live in the month, who were also live in the previous month.

I have calculated this in excel using this method but I am not clear on how to go about this in Python.
This is the excel formula I used.

```
COUNTIFS(B1:TE1,1,B2:TE2,1)
```

The resulting dataframe would look like this:

```
Customer    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   Customers_live_consecutive_months
11/30/2015  1   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0
12/31/2015  0   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   2
1/31/2016   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   3
2/29/2016   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   2
3/31/2016   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   6
4/30/2016   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   5
5/31/2016   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `rolling`:

```
>>> (df.rolling(2).sum() == 2).sum(1)
0    0
1    2
2    3
3    2
4    6
5    5
6    6
dtype: int64

# df['Customers_live_consecutive_months'] = (df.rolling(2).sum() == 2).sum(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do with `shift`

```
((df.shift()==1)&(df.shift()==df)).sum(1)
Out[80]: 
0    0
1    2
2    3
3    2
4    6
5    5
6    6
dtype: int64
```